# Fail to access applet in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, jna, jsobject

I have an applet that should use WinAPI through JNA. The applet signed by its own key.
I've deployed it on the page like this:

```xml
<applet id="_TestApplet" code="TestApplet.class" archive="/Content/TestApplet.jar"
name="Test Applet" width="0" height="0" mayscript=""> 
<param name="codebase_lookup" value="false"> 
</applet>
```

In Chrome and FF all OK, but in IE 6,7,8 there is an exception:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Java Console doesn't contain any exception.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Why do 90% of the questions I see here to do with errors happening in just IE? Rhetorical question.

Comment: 1) What is the JS used to interact with the applet? Better still, what is the short HTML in which you can reproduce this error? 2) The applet should be deployed using [`deployJava.js`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to write the correct element for the browser. 3) `code="TestApplet.class"` should be `code="TestApplet"`.  The former is tolerated, but not correct. 4) `width="0" height="0"` Some browsers remove 0 sized elements.  Hide it with CSS.  5) `mayscript=""` is a ..'flag', not an attribute.  So simply `mayscript` will do.